# Twitter @Anywhere oauth_bridge_code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-oauth, twitter-anywhere

I'm having trouble with Twitter's implementation of an oauth_bridge_code for the @anywhere api.  I've seen a few walkthrough's on how to use this functionality but I can't seem to get the request to work for me.  I'm using Ruby on Rails with the oauth gem.  My code is as follows:

```
def callback
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(APP_CONFIG['twitter_key'], APP_CONFIG['twitter_secret'],
                                   :site => "http://api.twitter.com",
                                   :request_token_path => "/oauth/request_token",
                                   :authorize_path => "/oauth/authorize",
                                   :access_token_path => "/oauth/access_token",
                                   :http_method => :post)

    request = OAuth::AccessToken.new consumer
    json = request.post("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_bridge_code=#{params[:oauth_bridge_code]}")
end
```

I keep getting 401 unauthorized responses from the signed post request even though this is supposed to be working according to this walkthrough: http://blog.abrah.am/2010/09/using-twitter-anywhere-bridge-codes.html and a presentation from Matt Harris on slideshare.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong (besides possibly trying to hit functionality that may not be in place)?  Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is in fact working.  I was passing in the wrong parameter on the post ajax call to my callback action.  Blurry-eyed and tired after a long week of coding will have you making simple yet agonizing mistakes I guess!